# C# generic repository used for unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern

I have the following fake repository that I use for unit testing.  How would I implement the Attach(T entity) method in this repository?

(In my real repository, the Attach(T entity) method is used to attach an object to my Entity Framework 4 data context).

```
public class FakeRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private static List<T> entities = new List<T>();

    public IQueryable<T> Entities
    {
        get { return entities.AsQueryable(); }
    }

    public T New()
    {
        return new T();
    }

    public void Create(T entity)
    {
        entities.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        entities.Remove(entity);
    }

    public void Attach(T entity)
    {
        //How to implement Attach???
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        //Do nothing
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this, you have to ask yourself "what is the purpose of "`Attach`?" You probably know that the point is to tell the repository "this object is persisted in the database but you aren't currently tracking it; I have made updates to it and I want you to commit them when I tell you to submit your changes."

Thus, to test that `Attach` is working properly, you should maintain a collection of attached objects and add an entity to this collection when it is passed a parameter to `Attach`.

So, the simplest implementation would be

```
entities.Add(entity);
```

but you could consider something more fine-grained. Note that you need to expose a method that lets you assert that the entity was successfully attached (in EF4 you can use `ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry`).

Answer (score 1):

get rid of the static word on the entities member. Now just do

```
enitities.Add(entity)
```